# Type information not passed with new/malloc, only size_t

Tags: c++

**EDITED: reworded question.**

When new and malloc are called, the size of the block of memory to be allocated is passed:

```
void* malloc(size_t);
void* operator new(size_t);
```

is it possible to get type information, i.e. so you could do a sizeof(T) where T was the type the memory was being allocated for:

```
T t = new T;
```

I'd like to overload new and malloc but require the type information not just the size of the memory being allocated.

**FURTHER EDIT:**

The reason I am doing this is that I will overload malloc. This function will inspect the size of the memory being allocated and allocate from a particualr memory pool:

```
        template <int v> struct int2type { value = v };

        inline void* malloc(const std::size_t sz)
        {
            if(sz <= 64)
            {
                size_obj* ptr = malloc(nggt::core::int2type<sizeof(size_obj) + (sz % 8)>);
                ptr->sz = sz;
                return ptr+1;
            }
            else if(sz <= 128)
            {
                size_obj* ptr = malloc(nggt::core::int2type<sizeof(size_obj) + 128>);
                ptr->sz = sz;
                return ptr+1;
            }
            else
            {
                return TSuper::malloc(sz);
            }
        }


        inline void* malloc(const nggt::core::int2type<sizeof(size_obj) + 8> sz)
        {
            return m_heap8.malloc(sz.value);
        }

        inline void* malloc(const nggt::core::int2type<sizeof(size_obj) + 16> sz)
        {
            return m_heap16.malloc(sz.value);
        }
```

There are also supporintg free overloads using a freelist to return memory to a pool. Problem is I can't use `size_t sz` in a template as it's not known at compile time. If I could get the type information I could do `sizeof(T)` and be done!

Cheers,
Graeme

Comment: What do you mean by "what calls these"?  Note also that `new` does *not* take a `size_t` (it basically takes anything that's convertible to integral type).

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't understand your kind of English.

Comment: What do you need that for?  What purpose do you have in mind?

Comment: Edited to include background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new with the `std::size_t` argument is commonly known as non-[placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).  The `std::size_t` argument is passed in by default to let the operating system know how many bytes to allocate for the object you are creating.  You, yourself, don't need to provide it to the new declaration.

Edit:

In response to your edit.  It's common practice if you are overloading the new operator to

1. place it within the namespace you would like it to be called from
2. Avoid a namespace new if you can make specific news for your objects.  (that is, there is behavior specific to each class, why not place it with the class itself)
3. The first argument should be the `std::size_t` which you don't need to worry about.  It'll be handled for you.

Everything else after that is all yours:

```
struct MyObject{
    MyObject* operator new(std::size_t s, const char* message){
        cout << "Creating an object of size " << size_of(MyObject) << endl;
        return new MyObject();
    }
};
```

You can even use the "old" new in your call of your "new" new.

Further Edit:

In response to your next edit, don't call your own malloc, malloc.  Instead, call it some other name.  If you're writing C++, malloc has no place within your code what so ever unless you're dealing with some legacy application.  In C++, you should only be touching the new operator.

Comment: Possible solution but I'd like to where possible not tie a memory allocator to a class. I guess I could template the class with an allocator and say using TAllocator...


Added another edit to the post.

Comment: `void* new( std::size_t )` is not placement new, but rather the signature of the `new` operator. This part of the language is quite confusing as there are different related things that share the same name: new.

Comment: BTW, *placement new* is a form of a *new expression* (which is a call) where extra arguments are passed to the allocation function, such as `new (arg) type`, which will call an allocator `void* new (std::size_t, ArgType)`. Note that the difference is that of caller/callee.